# How are the general skills for complete factorization of arbitrary homogeneous order polynomials in $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

How are the general skills for complete factorization of arbitrary homogeneous order polynomials in $\mathbb{C}$ ?

For example:

$1.$ $a^2+b^2+c^2$

$2.$ $a^2+b^2-c^2$

$3.$ $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$

$4.$ $a^2+b^2+c^2-d^2$

$5.$ $pa^2+qb^2+rc^2$ , where $p,q,r$ are non-zero constants

$6.$ $pa^2+qb^2+rc^2+sd^2$ , where $p,q,r,s$ are non-zero constants

Comment: What do you mean by "how are the general skills"?

Comment: @GregMartin, I think it is similar to meeting someone you know who is married, and you say "How are the children?" to be polite.

Comment: @GregMartin, I mean the general method or procedure.